# Why is $(BA)^* = A^*B^*$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $U, W,V$ are vector spaces and $A: V \to W$ and $B: W \to U$, why is the pullback operator $$(BA)^*\omega = A^* B^* \omega$$ where $\omega$ is an alternating form

[Source](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-101-analysis-ii-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lecture21.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is why the order of $A,B$ is reversed, this is as usual because the pullback is inserting maps *between* the direct object $\omega$ and *its* arguments. If $x$ abbreviates the arguments of the form (in fact composed of multiple values in the case of an alternating form) one has by definition
$$
  ((BA)^*\omega)(x)=\omega(BA(x))=(B^*\omega)(A(x))=(A^*(B^*\omega))(x),
$$
whence by abstraction of$~x$ one has $(BA)^*\omega=A^*(B^*\omega)$. Note that it couldn't be otherwise: since $\omega$ is a form on $U$ and $A:V\to W$ there is nothing $A^*$ can do directly to $\omega$.